# ASP:label and javascript getElementById

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to get the value of the `Text` property of an `asp:label` with Javascript's `document.getElementById` method, using the following code

```
<asp:Label ID="lblThis" runat="server" Visible="False" Text="this is a label" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var lblThis = document.getElementById('<%= lblThis.ClientID %>')
    var lblThisText = lblThis.innerText
    alert(lblThisText)
</script>
```

When I open the page, nothing happens.  I am not a javascript guy, so I have no idea where I'm going wrong.  I also am not trying to set any properties here, just read the value of an `asp:label` into javscript.

Any tips, pointers, or help given is appreciated.

UPDATE

I have replaced `Visible="false"` with `style="display:none"` as per [Mennan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11264150/312777), and now get an alert with "undefined".  The right direction, but I'm still not there yet.

UPDATE

I have a working chunk of code now.  `innerText` had nothing, but `innerHTML` had the right string.  Correct code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblThis" runat="server" style="display:none" Text="this is a label" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var lblThis = document.getElementById('<%= lblThis.ClientID %>')
    var lblThisText = lblThis.innerHTML
    alert(lblThisText)
</script>
```

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to terminate each line with a semi-colon;

Comment: I'd suggest using <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnThis" runat="server" Value="This is a hidden field." /> instead of a Label, if you do not need to display the value of the label on the page.

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with what you have in the code you have in your question. Is this all or do you have anything else in the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<asp:Label ID="lblThis" runat="server" style="display:none" Text="this is a label" />
```

Not

```
Visible="False"
```

Comment: Because invisible items not loaded on page so you cant access it , display:none means "load but hide it"

Answer (score 1):

Did you spell javascript wrong in the script tag type?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Also, when you use the "Visible" attribute, the control is not even sent to the page. It's not the same as using "display: none" in the styling. You need to set the styling for "display" as "none" and then javascript will find the element.